# (SOLVED) While and Cursor Return Duplicate Records in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have two identical tables, Source and Target. The source table is updated daily. At the end of the day, I want to compare these two tables and write the changes to a new table. I want to add the type of the change as a column while writing to the new table. Like 'new_row' if a new record has arrived, or updated_row if the 'new' column of an already existing record has been updated to 'x' or 'y'. I am getting the difference between two tables by id column.

[image: LocalTempTable]

I'm trying to do this with a while loop and cursor, but the records are returned to the table as duplicates. The result I want to get is as follows:

[image: expected_output]

However, I am getting the following result. It needs to have 3 records. There should be 2 new_rows and one different_row.

[image: wrong_output]

My code:

```
DECLARE @id nvarchar(10) 
DECLARE @New  nvarchar(100)

DECLARE NewCursor CURSOR 
FOR

SELECT [id],[New] FROM #LocalTempTable 

OPEN NewCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM NewCursor INTO @id,@New


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            IF @New = 'x' OR @New = 'y'
                BEGIN   
                        INSERT INTO [Result_Table]
                        SELECT 'new_row',@id,@New
                        FROM #LocalTempTable
                END 
            ELSE            
                BEGIN   
                        INSERT INTO [Result_Table]
                        SELECT 'new_row',@id,@New
                        FROM #LocalTempTable
                        INSERT INTO [Result_Table]
                        SELECT 'different_row',@id,@New
                        FROM #LocalTempTable

                END 
    FETCH NEXT FROM NewCursor INTO @id,@New
    END


CLOSE NewCursor
DEALLOCATE NewCursor
```

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you; we can't use an image of text. Take the time to post your data sample data as DDL and DML statements, and your expected results as well formatted tabular `text` or a markdown table. Also, why are you using a `CURSOR` here? SQL is a set based language, and a `CURSOR` (and `WHILE`) is the complete opposite of that; they are awfully slow.

Comment: While and cursor came to my mind first. What else can I use?

Comment: You don't need to `insert ... from #LocalTempTable`. Just `insert result_table values ('new_row', @id, @new)`. But yeah, no need for a cursor in the first place.

Comment: *"What else can I use?"* A normal `INSERT`? `INSERT INTO... SELECT...FROM`. A `CURSOR`, in truth, should be one of the *last* things that comes to mind, not the first.

Comment: I think there are some other oddities here as well. For example, if the first column of `results_table` is determined entirely from `new`, why do we need both values in the `results_table`? It seems redundant. Also, is it actually your intent to insert two rows into `results_table` when `new` is not X or Y? If so that does make the insert very slightly more complicated than it otherwise would be, but still doesn't require a cursor.

Comment: @allmhuran thank you for your help. I used cursor because it returns multiple rows. I did as you said and it worked as I wanted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.